# YII2 Login Manager

Tags: php, session, yii2

Lets say i have 2 projects using Yii2, i store it on my `/opt/lampp/htdocs` `A` and `B folders`.
When i tried to login to the second project, the first project i logged on is logout.
For example when i login on `B project` after logged in `A project`, `A project` is logged out.
And when i login on `A project` after logged in `B project`, `B project` is logged out.
Are they share same `session` or what?
Thank you.

Comment: are the 2 projects sharing the same DB ? and how is the authentication process handled ? (is it the already built in code from advanced template, an extension, your own token based class,...)

Comment: Ni,they have their own db.. Authentication using built in function.but it has same result when i open my project using yii2 starter kit

Comment: if they are not sharing the same user table or storing the cookie related authkey in the same place, then i guess they are sharing the same `cookieValidationKey` value. you'll find this under your config file > components > request. try to check that. each app should have its own `cookieValidationKey`.

Comment: i have check that,..
they have different cookieValidationKey ..

Comment: ok. i think that both app `session` and `user` components should be manually configured. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to manually config each app `user` and `session` components as follow :

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', // or whatever user class you are using
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => 'app1_user', // should be unique in each app
        'path'=>'/path_app_1/web'  // path to app 1.
    ]
],
'session' => [
    'name' => 'app1_session_id', // should be unique in each app
    'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/path_app_1/runtime', // unique folder to store app 1 related session data
],
```